# Creating a string from a list of words so that the string is 25 characters long

Tags: python, string, formatting, format, substring

Have a string:

s = "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country. Time is of the essence friends."

I want to divide s into substrings 25 characters in length like this:

```
"Now  is  the time for all\n",
"good  men  to come to the\n",
"aid   of  their  country.\n",
"Time  is  of the essence,\n",
"friends."
```

or

```
Now  is  the time for all
good  men  to come to the
aid   of  their  country.
Time  is  of the essence,
friends.
```

using spaces to pad the string 'equally' starting on the left to create a substring 25 characters.

Using split() I can divide the string s into a list of lists of words 25 characters long:

```
d=[]
s=0
c = a.split()
for i in c:
    s+=len(i)
    if s <= 25:
        d.append(i)
    else:
        s=0  
        d=[]
    d.append(i)

result:
    d=['Now is the time for all', 'good men to come to the', 'aid of their country.',  'Time is of the essence', 'friends.']
```

Then use this list d to build the string t

I don't understand how I can pad in between the words in each group of words to reach a length of 25.  It involves some circular method but I haven't found that method yet.

Comment: Check if this [link](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/414870-align-text-string-using-spaces-between-words-to-fi/) helps.

Comment: That definitely helped Cavin.